# How to auto fit input field after dynamically added spans?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve same functionality as StackOverflow has for adding tags on posting new Question.

Here spans are added dynamically using input field next to it.

For example:

```
<div>
    <div id="multiple-span">
       <span>Item 1<span>
       <span>Item 2<span>
       ...
       <span>Item n<span>
    </div>
    <div id="input-auto-fit">
       <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to achieve it using css?

[image]

I tried with `display:table-cell` for both inner `div` but `input` field is not auto-fit in outer div.

Comment: You can check how it's done on SO.

Comment: if you're willing to use jQuery there is a nice(if not a bit bloated) library https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use table and table-cell too, with some tweaks as follows.

```css
#outer-box {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#multiple-span, #input-auto-fit {
    display: table-cell;
}
#multiple-span span {
    background: gold;
    padding: 4px;
}
#input-auto-fit  {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
#input-auto-fit input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-box">
    <div id="multiple-span">
        <span>Item 1</span>
        <span>Item 2</span>
        <span>Item n</span>
    </div>
    <div id="input-auto-fit">
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `width:100%` along with `display:table` solved my issue. Thanks.